# WIFI card rtl8821ce cannot connect to 5GHz networks

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I'm currently on Ubuntu20.04(dual boot with Windows), and after too many attempts to install a driver for my laptop WIFI to get work. Well, it works..

because I'm new to Linux system and i don't know so much detail, i used [Tomaspinho](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) driver, which was the easiest way for me and followed [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPfLVsyQU_A) (the driver also suggested by some askubuntu highlights)

it connects but only connects to the Access Point via 2.4GHz. As far as i know, my WIFI card(PCIe Realtek 8821ce) capable of connecting to 5GHz networks, i know that because i connected to 5GHz network on my Windows, here is the output of `iwconfig wlo1`:

```
:~$ iwconfig wlo1
      wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TISHKNET"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: 50:68:0A:C1:81:62   
      Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=94/100  Signal level=-56 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

i read an article that says that my card should be an`IEEE 802.11ac` to be able to connect to 5GHz networks, what i can do to connect my 5GHz network? any advice would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo iw dev wlo1 set power_save off` where `wlo1` should be your wifi device id

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new user not expert in any way.
I had a problem with my card when installing Linux Mint 20.4
then again when experimenting with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.4

Also, when searching "Additional Drivers" nothing appeared for this device.

I found the following on line (I think it was "Ask Ubuntu"!?)

- Connect to internet (I used an android phone with usb tethering)
- Open Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then copy/paste one line at a time:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821cu
```

Wireless icon appeared, enabled my phone as a Hotspot, system requested the password, connected immediately with good speed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after installing **Ubuntu 20.04** on my **Lenovo IdeaPad**.  Issuing the command `iw list`, I found some of the 5GHz frequencies are disabled by the Realtek 8821CE driver and some other channels are not.  The old 5G channel I used was 5560MHz (channel-112) and it is one of the disabled channels.  I then changed my wifi router's 5G setting to use another channel that is not disabled and now I can connect to my 5G wifi without problem.

See this site (https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues/34) for details if you want.

Hope this helps!